# How to find vds/hosting with the best ping that I can have?

Tags: web-hosting, ping, network-speed, vds

I'm living in tajikistan, and I want to purchase vps/dedicated server or at least good hosting  outside of my country. One of important thing I want is to have a GOOD ping. For example ping to `google.com` is `200ms` and ping to `stackoverflow.com` is `350ms`. Sites that are hosted in the local hostings are working with `50ms`.

Now the question is: How can I find hosting/vps/ds with **best** ping that I can have? Is there any services or ways to find them?

Comment: Ping is not an abosolute value without context. Ping(source, target) is better defined. By saing "GOOD ping" do you mean ping from where? (from you? your customers?)

Answer (score 0):

Well each hop adds some latency so you should be looking for a datacenter / provider in your area with a decent uplink. As you are looking for a provider outside your country I'd look in the neighbourhood (India, China, Russia ...)

You could check some of the websites listing hosting companies or you just google for it *e.g. vps hosting russia* and then check this provider's ping manually (or even script that).